# Stripe take payment using saved card laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

How can i use saved card in stripe for next payment in future using stripe in Laravel framework?
I have tried to find out in Stripe official documentation but i could not find the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to ask the Laravel/Cashier community for more advice, but it looks like you can retrieve a customer's payment methods like this ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#retrieving-payment-methods)):

```
$paymentMethods = $user->paymentMethods();
```

If you're referring to use with future invoices (eg for subscriptions) you may want to set a default ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#updating-the-default-payment-method)):

```
$user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution with the help of stripe document.
Here is the reference link https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web

With the use of demo i got success. And its working properly.

Thanks for another answers.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using [Stripe's future payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse). On that documentation one can find `PHP` examples that can be translated into Laravel.

Depending on the use case, [`Laravel Cashier`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/billing) might also be of relevance.

A Stripe account will be required (here's the [Sign Up page](https://dashboard.stripe.com/register)).

[Here](https://stripe.com/docs/development/quickstart/php) one can find how to get up and running with a Stripe integration in PHP.

Even though related with Django, [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73614292/7109869) on a similar issue might be of relevance.