# Appropriate payment data management practice

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, android-pay, applepay, square

I often build payment integrations in my applications. When I receive responses from PayPal or square I am usually able to record a bunch of data from the payment partner. Some of that data I could use to maintain a local copy of the transaction which occurred on the payment facilitator's service.

Often I record the data which I feel supports the needs of the application in question. But I am interested in what is considered standard practice for this data management?

Answer (score 0):

Your question about "standard practice" is fairly broad, but it is safe to store object IDs and other non-card data returned from the Stripe API.
https://stripe.com/docs/security#out-of-scope-card-data

Other data protection/privacy laws may apply to your business.

(From a previous answer on a similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577523/12474862 )

Comment: Thanks very much, I understand this is a very broad topic but felt that there must be some type of regularly followed procedures or design patterns. Thanks a lot!